# Include all document fields at all levels based on the field value

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

i want to create roll based menu if some having permission to view **cavoucher,puvendor** forms here i know only form name nothing else and also the form name could be any where defined in the document so how can i get the result only matched content along with the parent

```
   [ { 
"_id" : ObjectId("57ef642fd4f27bb41b697314"), 
"menuDesc" : "Cash Module", 
"formName" : "", 
"subMenu1" : [
    {
        "menuDesc" : "Setup", 
        "formName" : "", 
        "subMenu2" : [
            {
                "menuDesc" : "Setup Bank Details", 
                "formName" : "cabank", 
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
       "menuDesc" : "Vouchers", 
        "formName" : "", 
        "subMenu2" : [
            {
                "menuDesc" : "Maintain Cash Voucher", 
                "formName" : "cavoucher", 
            }, 
            {
                "menuName" : "Paid Voucher", 
                "menuDesc" : "Maintain Paid Voucher", 
                "formName" : "capaidvchr", 
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
},
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("57ef6464d4f27bb41b697316"), 
"menuDesc" : "Purchase Module", 
"formName" : "", 
"subMenu1" : [
    {
        "menuDesc" : "Maintain Vendors", 
        "formName" : "puvendor" 
        }
]
}]
```

the result i am looking for

```
    [{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("57ef642fd4f27bb41b697314"),
"menuDesc" : "Cash Module", 
"formName" : "", 
"subMenu1" : [
    {
        "menuDesc" : "Vouchers", 
        "formName" : "", 
        "subMenu2" : [
            {
                "menuDesc" : "Maintain Cash Voucher", 
                "formName" : "cavoucher", 
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
 },{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("57ef6464d4f27bb41b697316"), 
"menuDesc" : "Purchase Module", 
"formName" : "", 
"subMenu1" : [
    {
        "menuDesc" : "Maintain Vendors", 
        "formName" : "puvendor" 
        }
]
}}
```

I don't know at which level has the value matched please suggest any possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) in MongoDB.

Here in your case you have two nested arrays `subMenu1` and `subMenu2` first [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) them and then use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to achieve the result.

Mongo Shell Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$subMenu1"}, 
    {$unwind:"$subMenu1.subMenu2"},
    {$match:{"subMenu1.subMenu2.formName":"cavoucher"}}
 ])
```

Comment: when unwinding my result converts to object. I want my sub documents to be in array....